# Finding correct subclass in class structure

Tags: java, class, polymorphism, subclass

I have one class, let's call it `ClassA`, and a bunch of subclasses of it, and subsequent subclasses of those classes. `ClassA`, and every class below it takes a `String` at an argument in their constructor. I have a bunch of `String` objects that I need to 'convert' into subclasses of `ClassA`.

The current way I am doing it is with is `isType(String)` method that checks if the `String` is an instance of that subclass, but it seems like very bad programming technique to use a huge if-else or switch-case statement to find the correct type of `ClassA` that the `String` is. It there a common way to go down a sub-class structure, or is the way that I have been doing it okay?

The purpose of this is that I am making a scripting language (for a fun project) and I need to be able identify what something is. (Data type that is)

Example code:

```
public static boolean isType(String data) {
    data = data.trim();
    return edu.ata.script.data.Boolean.isType(data)
            || edu.ata.script.data.Integer.isType(data)
            || edu.ata.script.data.Double.isType(data)
            || DATA_STORAGE.contains(data)
            || ReturningMethod.isType(data)
            || edu.ata.script.data.String.isType(data);
}

public static Data get(String data) {
    data = data.trim();
    /*:)*/ if (edu.ata.script.data.Boolean.isType(data)) {
        return edu.ata.script.data.Boolean.get(data);
    } else if (edu.ata.script.data.Integer.isType(data)) {
        return edu.ata.script.data.Integer.get(data);
    } else if (edu.ata.script.data.Double.isType(data)) {
        return edu.ata.script.data.Double.get(data);
    } else if (DATA_STORAGE.contains(data)) {
        return (Data) DATA_STORAGE.get(data);
    } else if (ReturningMethod.isType(data)) {
        return ReturningMethods.getMethodValue(data);
    } else if (edu.ata.script.data.String.isType(data)) {
        // Last option because everything is accepted.
        return edu.ata.script.data.String.get(data);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse data - " + data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the method isType(String string) your hack to know which class is it? For what I'm understanding the only thing you really want is to know if a given class is or not a subclass of ClassA, is this correct or am I not following you?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I have a string that is basically either ClassA or some subclass of ClassA. I can evaluate if the string is a ClassA by using isType(String), but it seems like a bad way to do it (And there are a ton of subclasses to check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was indeed understanding something totally different, so I'm re-editing this answer.

I suspect that you're working in some sort of importation script or something and that the `edu.ata.script.data.*` are the ClassB, ClassC, etc that you were writing and they know how to convert stuff from one format to another... (This is just guessing)

My suggestion to get rid of all the if then else in the `get(String data)` method is that you implement a [chain of responsability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). That way you can have a chain that registers the several edu.ata.script.data.* in a List and then you iterate through that list until one of them returns true for the isType(string) knowing which subclass you want to use to process the string.

To remove the list of ORs in the `isType(String data)` method is a bit trickier and probably this is a bit over enginnering, but you can do the following:

1. Look in your classpath for classes that are assignableFrom your class
2. Then when you would retrieve all the classes that were assignable by your own you would have to invoke via reflection the isType of each one to know the result

   I know you might find yourself a bit lost regarding the 1st point, best way is to look into [ResolverUtil](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.stripes/stripes/1.4.3/net/sourceforge/stripes/util/ResolverUtil.java#ResolverUtil.loadImplementationsFromContextClassloader%28java.lang.Class%29) class from Stripes Framework where they do that in the method `loadImplementationsFromContextClassloader`

Comment: From what I understand I think the problem is that you're using a "string" to identify the type of each Class, when you can use the Class object itself. Or maybe I'm still not following you. If so I suggest you to post a bit more of code so I can understand a bit better in order to be able to help you

Comment: Made an edit with real code from the project. Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: I edited my answer, I think you'll find it more suitable for the question you were asking

Comment: Thanks very much. Marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to parse a string into an instance of the correct subclass, by passing it to each subclass's `isType` method until one says it can handle it. I would have each subclass register a parser object which can inspect the string and produce an initialised instance of the corresponding subclass if possible.

Interface for the Parsers:

```
package edu.ata.script.data;

interface ScriptParser {
    public boolean isType(String data);
    public Data    get(String data) throws UnparsableException;
}
```

An example Data subclass:

```
package edu.ata.script.data;

public class Boolean extends Data {

// Empty constructor for reflection purposes
public Boolean() {};

public Boolean(String data) {
    // Initialise from string
}

public ScriptParser getParser() {
    return new ScriptParser() {
        public boolean isType(String data) {
           return "true".equals(data) || "false".equals(data);
        }

        public Data get(String data) throws UnparsableException {
            if (isType(data)) {
                return new edu.ata.script.data.Boolean(data);
            } else {
                throw new UnparsableException(data);
            }
        }
    };
}

}
```

Then you can just build a list of classes into a collection before parsing:

```
List<ScriptParser> parsers = new LinkedList<>();
parsers.add(new edu.ata.script.data.Boolean().getParser());
parsers.add(new edu.ata.script.data.Integer().getParser());
parsers.add(new edu.ata.script.data.Double().getParser());
...
```

The above could also be achieved via reflection.

Then you can parse the data with a simple loop, no matter how many data types you end up supporting:

```
public Data get(String data) throws SyntaxErrorException {
    for (ScriptParser sp:parsers) {
        if (sp.isType(data)) {
            try {
                return sp.get(data);
            } catch (UnparsableException e) {
                // This shouldn't happen, but better safe than sorry!
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    throw new SyntaxErrorException(data);
}
```